# Unable to return string properly in C++ for some range

Tags: c++, string, pointers, return, reverse

I've made one C++ program using pointers and functions to return the reverse of a string. When the range char p[] in the function rev is low like 25 (less than. 145), the output is like ►↕☻ ☺♠♥, it doesn't reverse, when the range is higher than 145, it works fine in gcc, for Borland TurboC, the minimum range must be 65 otherwise the program prints strange values instead of reversing it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char str[20];
  int  l;
  char* p1;
  //clrscr();
  gets(str);

  l=strlen(str);
  char* rev(char*,int);
  p1=rev(str,l);
  puts(p1);
  return 0;
  //getch();
}

char * rev(char* a,int l1)
{
  char p[25]; // HERE: higher than 146 is working
  int c=0;
    for(l1=l1-1;l1>=0;l1--)
    {
       p[c]=a[l1];
       c++;
    }
  p[c]=NULL;
  return(p);
}
```

---

Comment: Undefined behaviour. If you are not able to use raw arrays and pointers properly, don´t do it, but use `std::string`. (Btw., don´t play around with SO´s editor buttons)

Comment: but using strcpy() function to copy the pointer p1 to a string and displaying is working fine

Comment: So what? UB doesn´t mean has to crash everytime, but it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `rev` array `char p[25];`  is a local object of the function. After exiting the function it will not be alive and in general can be destroyed, that is the memory occupied by it can be overwritten by other object or function.

So the returned pointer to the first character of this array is invalid and the program has undefined behaviour.

It is unclear why the array in the function is defined with the size equal to magic number 25. If the second argument passed to the function will be greater than 25 then again there will be a problem because the memory will be overwritten beyond the array.

Also the design of the function is not good. Either the function reverses a string "in place" or copy in the reverse order the sourse array in the destination array and in this case the destination array has to be a function parameter.

And it is a bad idea to use C IO functions in C++ program. Moreover function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported any more by the C Standard.

The function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

char * reverse_copy( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( s2 );
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) s1[i] = s2[n - i - 1];
    s1[i] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    char str1[N];
    char str2[N];

    std::cin.getline( str2, N );

    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << ::reverse_copy( str1, str2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

If to enter phrase

```
Hello, Priyal Kumar
```

then the program output will be

```
Hello, Priyal Kumar
ramuK layirP ,olleH
```

Comment: thanks, :)  but but using strcpy() function to copy the pointer p1 to a string and displaying is working fine

Comment: @Priyal Kumar It is simply a bad approach. In fact you copy the string twice because the reverse operation is also some sort of a copy operation. And moreover these two operations are not logically connected. Somebody can forget that he need at first to copy the string and only then to call the reverse function.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
char p[25]
```

in function rev is only declared locally. When you'll reach the end of function, all of the local variables will be deleted (including array p). The easiest way to fix this is to change char p[25] to:

```
char *p = new char[25]
```

but beware, this might cause memory leaks if you won't free memory when you won't need it any more. I'd recommend you use *std::string* or take a look at some built in functions like *strrev* in *string.h*.

Comment: but using strcpy() function to copy the pointer p1 to a string and displaying is working fine, thanks for answering